# Babel numbers format_currency function

Tags: python, python-2.7, currency, python-babel

I am working on a site where we use many languages and in order to display the price/currency accordingly we make use of babel library. The issue is when calling the format_currency it returns always the cent part if even if the price is explicitly casted into an integer.

Example:

```
>>> print format_currency(100, 'EUR', locale='fr_FR')
100,00 €

>>> print format_currency(int(100), 'EUR', locale='fr_FR')
100,00 €
```

Is it a way around this so that the return value excludes the cent part to have something like

```
>>> print format_currency(int(100), 'EUR', locale='fr_FR')
100 €
```

Answer (score 6):

You must add currency_digits parameter with format to achieve your goal

```
>>> print(format_currency(100, 'EUR', locale='fr_FR')
100,00 €
>>> print(format_currency(100, 'EUR', locale='fr_FR', currency_digits=False))
100,00 €
>>> print(format_currency(100, 'EUR', format=u'#,##0\xa0¤', locale='fr_FR'))
100,00 €
>>> print(format_currency(100, 'EUR', format=u'#,##0\xa0¤', locale='fr_FR', currency_digits=False))
100 €
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a custom format:

```
format_currency(100, 'EUR', format=u'#,##0\xa0¤', locale='fr_FR')
```

See the [LDML markup spec](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/numbers.html) for more details; the `\xa0` byte is a [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00a0) character; rather than a regular space.

For `fr_FR` the default is `#,##0.00\xa0¤`, and the `.00` part signals that a decimal portion should be printed with two digits, padded if not present. My example above simply removed the decimal portion, you also could use `.##` to allow for a fraction if the number is not an exact integer, but note that in that case a `.5` value is printed without a 2nd digit!

Demo:

```
>>> from babel.numbers import format_currency
>>> print format_currency(100, 'EUR', format=u'#,##0\xa0¤', locale='fr_FR')
100 €
>>> print format_currency(100.0, 'EUR', format=u'#,##0.##\xa0¤', locale='fr_FR')
100 €
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution involves re-writing every format depending on the selected locale? In the case where the locale is not constant, is there a way to truncate the number for an arbitrary locale?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/478#issuecomment-290365787).

Answer (score 3):

In the cases where the locale is arbitrary, it would be painful to rewrite the format manually, here is [a solution](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/478#issuecomment-290365787) that seems to work.

Just in case here is the code proposed by [Akx](https://github.com/akx) on this github issue:

```py
from babel import Locale
from babel.numbers import decimal

def custom_format_currency(value, currency, locale):
    value = decimal.Decimal(value)
    locale = Locale.parse(locale)
    pattern = locale.currency_formats['standard']
    force_frac = ((0, 0) if value == int(value) else None)
    return pattern.apply(value, locale, currency=currency, force_frac=force_frac)

print(custom_format_currency('2.50', 'EUR', 'fi'))
print(custom_format_currency('2.00', 'EUR', 'fi'))
```