# Python - 'babel' package - currency - how to remove cents/pennies etc.?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
print(format_currency(100000, currency="GBP", locale="en_GB"))
```

And the output is:

> £100,000.00

Whereas I want the output to be:

> £100,000

I have checked the documentation for Babel: https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html and can see no way to do this.

Any advice on how to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426217/babel-numbers-format-currency-function

Comment: Yes, thank you Thomas + FlyingTeller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a way to do it in babel, that would be helpful, however I can use string formatting instead:

```
currency = "£{:,.0f}".format(100000)
```

> output: '£100,000'